# Wagtail: Get previous or next sibling

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm creating a page with wagtail where I need to know the previous and next sibling of the current page:

In my portrait page model, I tried to define two methods to find the correct urls, but I'm missing a crucial part. To get the first sibling, I can just do the following:

```
class PortraitPage(Page):

    ...

    def first_portrait(self):
        return self.get_siblings().live().first().url
```

There is the `first()` and `last()` method, but there doesn't seem to be a `next()` or `previous()` method to get the direct neighbours (in the order that they are arranged in the wagtail admin).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After going through the debugger for a while, I found out that wagtail already has two methods: `get_prev_sibling()` and `get_next_sibling()`.

So the methods could look like this (accounting for the first page in the previous method and the last item in the next method):

```
def prev_portrait(self):
    if self.get_prev_sibling():
        return self.get_prev_sibling().url
    else:
        return self.get_siblings().last().url

def next_portrait(self):
    if self.get_next_sibling():
        return self.get_next_sibling().url
    else:
        return self.get_siblings().first().url
```

Comment: I imagine that it comes from the page model, but I haven't looked into it. I just did a `dir(self)` and looked through the available methods. And it works. Which version of wagtail do you have? I'm working on v.1.0b1

Comment: @rnevius Ah, here we go, it is only mentioned in the release notes of wagtail 0.4:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/releases/0.4.html

Comment: Hi @nils and @rnevius, the `get_prev_sibling()` and `get_next_sibling()` methods come from Treebeard, which handles Wagtail's page hierarchy, and is documented here:

https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.61/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.get_next_sibling

P.S. @nils, if you're using 1.0b1 you should check out 1.0b2 which we released today: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/releases/tag/v1.0b2

Comment: Thanks for the info @tomd! I'm running beta2 as we speak ;-)

Comment: @tomd I just realized that "get_next_sibling()" doesn't contain the fields that I defined in the Page-model (eg. "header_image"). Is there a way to access these as well?

Comment: @nils `.specific. will give you what you're after.

Comment: get_next_sibling() will also give you unpublished pages. I think this is the reason why it is not documented. What is the correct way doing this?

Answer (score 11):

[Django-Treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/) provides `get_next_sibling` and `get_prev_sibling` which will return your direct siblings in the tree, but these are not necessarily your next *published* sibling. To request those you can use:

```
prev = page.get_prev_siblings().live().first()
next = page.get_next_siblings().live().first()
```

Which can obviously also be chained with any other queryset operations.

Comment: is there any way to achieve the same result in a Django template?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version handling `non-published` siblings.

```python
def next_portrait(self):
    next_sibling = self.get_next_sibling()
    if next_sibling and next_sibling.live:
        return next_sibling.url
    else:
        next_published_siblings = self.get_next_siblings(
            inclusive=False
        ).live()
        if len(next_published_siblings):
            return next_published_siblings[0].url
        return self.get_siblings().live().first().url

def prev_portrait(self):
    previous_sibling = self.get_prev_sibling()
    if previous_sibling and previous_sibling.live:
        return previous_sibling.url
    else:
        previous_published_siblings = self.get_prev_siblings(
            inclusive=False
        ).live()
        if len(previous_published_siblings):
            return previous_published_siblings[0].url
        return self.get_siblings().live().last().url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define properties in your class that inherits from `Page`

### Siblings

If you want the siblings of an instance of `Page`, you can use the following (based on Danielle Madeley's answer):

```
class PortraitPage(Page):
    # ...
    @property
    def next_sibling(self):
        return self.get_next_siblings().live().first()

    @property
    def prev_sibling(self):
        return self.get_prev_siblings().live().first()
```

### Siblings of the same class

If you want the the siblings of `PortraitPage`, specify `self.__class__` in the `type` method as follows:

```
class PortraitPage(Page):
    # ...
    @property
    def next_sibling(self):
        return self.get_next_siblings().type(self.__class__).live().first()

    @property
    def prev_sibling(self):
        return self.get_prev_siblings().type(self.__class__).live().first()
```

### Template

If you want to use them in a template, after defining the properties, do the following:

```
{# This is a template #}
Previous Sibling: {{ page.next_sibling }}
Next Sibling: {{ page.prev_sibling }}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.get_siblings() falls over if you want to do any filtering based on properties only found in the subclass since the PageQuerySet results are of type Page.

For me, I have a blog index page that can be filtered by category or tag.
The bog detail page has cards for the next and previous blog post at the end.
I wanted those prev/next posts to be according to the filter I landed on that page from.

To get around this, you need to query the objects belonging to the subclass (eg BlogDetailPage), filter those, then get the prev/next post using *class.objects.sibling_of(self)*:

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    siblings = self.__class__.objects.sibling_of(self).live()
    category_filter = request.GET.get("category", None)
    tag_filter = request.GET.get("tag", None)
    if category_filter:
        siblings = siblings.filter(categories__slug__in=category_filter.split(","))
        context["filter"] = '?category=' + category_filter
    elif tag_filter:
        siblings = siblings.filter(tags__slug__in=tag_filter.split(','))
        context["filter"] = '?tag=' + tag_filter
    else:
        context["filter"] = ''
    context["next_post"] = siblings.filter(path__gt=self.path).first()
    context["previous_post"] = siblings.filter(path__lt=self.path).first()

    return context
```

I used `self.__class__.objects.sibling_of(self)` as this is in a super class with sub classed blog pages.