# Wagtail: Get siblings attributes

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, wagtail

I'm creating portfolio app. And on the inner page I'd like to give a link to the next portfolio record with it's thumbnail.

[Wagtail: Get previous or next sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345266/wagtail-get-previous-or-next-sibling) — Here is an answer on how to get the url. But it doesn't work for getting other attributes.

If i change 'url' in this method:

```py
def next_portfolio(self):
    if self.get_next_sibling():
        return self.get_next_sibling().url
    else:
        return self.get_siblings().first().url
```

To get not '.url' but '.thumbnail'

```
def next_portfolio(self):
    if self.get_next_sibling():
        return self.get_next_sibling().thumbnail
    else:
        return self.get_siblings().first().thumbnail
```

All I get is an error "'Page' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'". but it have. That's how my model looks like:

```
class PortfolioItem(Page):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = '', default = None)
    is_feautered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def next_portfolio_thumb(self):
    if self.get_next_sibling():
        return self.get_next_sibling().thumbnail
    else:
        return self.get_siblings().first()
```

It should be obvious way to get sibling attribute. Could you please point me on how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wagtail unit testing: Adding child pages converts them to base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529294/wagtail-unit-testing-adding-child-pages-converts-them-to-base-type)

Comment: @gasman thanks you, but I don't see how it answers my question

Comment: @gasman I've read your answer once again carefully to a linked question. And I understand how it could be connected to my question, but on practice I had no luck to get the result I'm looking for. Could you please give me a hint on how to write this function, as I am lost in this tree hierarchy. Thank you.

Comment: To retrieve the `thumbnail` property, you need the specific version of the page object: `self.get_next_sibling().specific.thumbnail` or `self.get_siblings().first().specific.thumbnail`.

Comment: @gasman Yes, thank you. It took some time for me, but I've got it. Your link kind of answers my question, but in a way someone more experienced would understand. here I've answered my own question in more detailed manner. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

So the answer to this question is following. 
User named @gasman answered here: [Wagtail unit testing: Adding child pages converts them to base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529294/wagtail-unit-testing-adding-child-pages-converts-them-to-base-type?noredirect=1&lq=1) on how to get attributes of hte specific page.

For this we use `.specific` property.

So first I've opened the shell by:

```
python manage.py shell
```

There I've imported models and my model:

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> from portfolio import PortfolioItem
```

After I've emulated current portfolio item, called it and got result of several attributes

```
>>> page = PortfolioItem.objects.get(title = "Project title1")
>>> page
<PortfolioItem: Project title1>
>>> page.thumbnail
<ImageFieldFile: thumb1.png>
```

Then I've created instance of "next" where I've called Wagtail's special `get_next_sibling()` function. As you can see, by itself it wouldn't return specific attributes of the record, but only common one (see the link on top). but after using `specific` property, you can get all the info you need from the record.

```
>>> next = page.get_next_sibling()
>>> next
<Page: Project title2>
>>> next.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'name'
>>> next.specific
<PortfolioItem: Project title2>
>>> next.specific.name
'Project name2'
```

So in my model I've created new function:

```
def next_port(self):
        if self.get_next_sibling():
            return self.get_next_sibling()
        else:
            return self.get_siblings().first()
```

And in the template I've used it this way:

```
<img src="/media/{{ self.next_port.specific.thumbnail }}">
```

If you have more elegant way of doing the same thing, please let me know.